# Pivot_longer with multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a table with output for two models. I would like to switch the direction of the table (columns become rows, rows become columns), but leaving the standard errors underneath the coefficients.

```
coef1 <-sample(4)
se1 <- sample(4)
coef2 <-sample(4)
se2 <- sample(4)

# brackets
se1 <- paste0("(", se1, ")")
se2 <- paste0("(", se2, ")")

#table
table <- rbind(coef1, se1, coef2, se2)

#colnames
colnames <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
colnames(table) <- colnames

table <- data.frame(table)
```

I would like the output to look similar to this.

[image]

I know the solution will be pivot_longer. something like this:

```
table_switch <- table %>% pivot_longer(names_to=cols, values_to=c(coef1, se1, coef2, se2))
```

I keep getting errors. Please help.

Edit:

Here is an example:

This is the table I have.

[image]

This is the table I would like:

[image]

Comment: Your sample data is a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`, and `pivot_longer` requires a frame. It might be easier/better to paste the output from `dput(table)` (of your real data) instead. (Or is that your problem ... that you're getting errors about pivot_longer/matrix?)

Comment: Also, do you want your frame values to have the literal string `"coef1"`, `"se1"` or are those variables and you want their values displayed?

Comment: Yes the values. Not literal strings.

Comment: @r2evans : Unfortunately, I cannot post the output table of my original data for security reasons. Also, converting to data.frame didn't solve my issue. This is the error msg I keep getting. "Error in is_call(expr, paren_sym) : argument "expr" is missing, with no default". Thanks for your help.